# Using database connection as a class: best practice?

Tags: database, class

I have db class which initiates connection to the database and all the queries are run through it.

Now I am having troubles with the fact that I don't know how to use it within other objects and also how to use it within functions.

For example if there is an object to process and display some data, then do I extend this object to the db class or else how do I get the connection for the $db in this class.

Also, how do I use the db connection in a function outside a class. Do I post the db class as a parameter or do I use GLOBAL $db;

All the "do I" are actually "should I", so please advice me what is best for performance and other pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

Usually frameworks provide a singleton instance of the database connection, which can be obtained via static method (or global function) that returns the encapsulated (static private) instance. This instance is created when the first call to this method is executed, for the next calls, it simply returns it.